# Offset Coordinates Selenium Visualiser

Tags: python, selenium, coordinates, offset

I've learned how to use `move_by_offset(x, y).perform()`
But now I'm wondering what x,y means

Is this the coordinate of a point that we put on axes and x and y are his coordinate ?

Answer (score 1):

```
move_by_offset(xoffset, yoffset)
```

Moving the mouse to an offset from current mouse position.

**Args:**

```
xoffset: X offset to move to, as a positive or negative integer.
yoffset: Y offset to move to, as a positive or negative integer.
```

official docs : [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.move_by_offset)

you may think like below :

> Moves the mouse from its current position (or 0,0) by the given
> offset. If the coordinates provided are outside the viewport (the
> mouse will end up outside the browser window) then the viewport is
> scrolled to match.

or in simple term **they are coordinates.**